# Liferay theme development using JBoss on Mac

Tags: macos, ant, liferay, jboss7.x

I am creating liferay themes using JBoss on my Mac. In the process of creating a theme, when I execute `ant deploy` on my terminal, I am getting following errors:

```
Buildfile:
/Users/saif/Desktop/Liferay/liferay-plugins-sdk-6.1.1/themes/g2y-b2b-theme/build.xml
     [copy] Copying 1 file to /usr/share/ant/lib

BUILD FAILED
/Users/saif/Desktop/Liferay/liferay-plugins-sdk-6.1.1/themes/g2y-b2b-theme/build.xml:5:
The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/saif/Desktop/Liferay/liferay-plugins-sdk-6.1.1/themes/build-common-theme.xml:7:
The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/saif/Desktop/Liferay/liferay-plugins-sdk-6.1.1/build-common-plugin.xml:5:
The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/saif/Desktop/Liferay/liferay-plugins-sdk-6.1.1/build-common.xml:68:
Failed to copy
/Users/saif/Desktop/Liferay/liferay-plugins-sdk-6.1.1/lib/ecj.jar to
/usr/share/ant/lib/ecj.jar due to java.io.FileNotFoundException
/usr/share/ant/lib/ecj.jar (Permission denied)

Total time: 0 seconds
```

Please help me to get rid of this and proceed further. What are the steps I should take in order to do this on a Mac? Please also tell me how to set up the environment variable of ANT on a Mac.

Comment: Your user account isn't going to have write access to /usr/share/ant/lib.   Can you post that section of build-common.xml?  How much of build.xml did you make and how much was provided?  Is it possible the source and destination for the copy are mixed up?

Answer (score 1):

When ant builds your theme and requires `ecj.jar` (the eclipse compiler for java) it typically downloads it from some internet repository and places it in `$ANT_HOME/lib`. It seems your `$ANT_HOME` is `usr/share/ant` and you don't have write access to that directory. Either download it manually and place it there or open up the directory write permissions for one build (then close it again).

You'll only need to do this once: When `ecj.jar` is on the classpath for ant, it will just be used for eternity.